# Применение правила замены буквы "в" на "г" в окончаниях фамилий

Tags: орфография, окончания

Мы на автомате применяем правило замены буквы "в" на "г" в окончании некоторых слов (ничего, всего, моего и т.д.). В том числе я лично использую это правило в отношении фамилий:

- Станиславский — Станиславского;
- Комаровский — Комаровского.

В одном из споров мне заявили, что это правило распространяетcя только на прилагательные, причастия и местоименные слова (в том числе, это написано в справочнике по орфографии и пунктуации). Но я помню, что в литературе данное правило применяется и в отношении фамилий. Имеется ли где-нибудь правило, затрагивающее имена собственные?

Comment: Это не замена, а прочтение.

Comment: Да, не совсем корректно составлен вопрос. Но править уже не стану.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пункте 146.6 "Справочника по правописанию и стилистике" Розенталя между делом упоминается, как пишутся русские фамилии на -ский, -цкий.

> 6. Иностранные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на гласный звук (кроме неударяемых -а, -я), не склоняются, например: романы Золя, открытия Араго, драмы Гюго, оперы Бизе, музыка Пуччини, пьесы Шоу.
>
> Нередко под это правило подводятся и славянские (польские и чешские) фамилии на -ски и -ы: романы Иоганнеса Бобровски, словарь Покорны (чешский лингвист), зверское убийство Джозефа Яблонски и его семьи. Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что тенденция к передаче подобных фамилий в соответствии с их звучанием в языке-источнике (ср. написание польских фамилий Глиньски, Лещиньская - с буквой ь перед ск) сочетается с традицией их передачи по русскому образцу в написании и склонении: произведения польского писателя Красинского, труды лингвиста Лер-Сплавинского, выступление певицы Евы Бандровской-Турской, концерт пианистки Черны-Стефаньской, статья Октавии Опульской-Данецкой и т. п. Чтобы избежать трудностей в функционировании подобных фамилий в русском языке, целесообразно оформлять их по образцу склонения русских мужских и женских фамилий на -ский, -цкий, -ый, -ая. Ср. падежные формы таких польских сочетаний, как Крайова Рада Народова: делегация Крайовой Рады Народовой, образование Крайовой Радой Народовой Временного правительства и т. п.

Отмечу, что фамилии на *"-ский"* происходят от прилагательных по принципу "житель *Москвы* — *московский* житель — просто *московский* — фамилия *Московский*". То есть когда вам сказали, что правило распространяется в числе прочего на прилагательные, — они не ошиблись.